# SwiftUI View and ViewModel Modifying with Binding and Observed variables

Tags: view, swiftui, properties, binding, viewmodel

I have a View and a ViewModel and would like to set some variables in the ViewModel and read AND set them in the View. In the ViewModel I have a @Published variable. When I try to modify the value of the variable in the View, the errors I get are: 'Cannot assign to property: '$testModel' is immutable' and 'Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Binding'. Is there a way to do this? The code I have now is as follows:

**View**

```
struct TestView: View {

@ObservedObject var testModel: TestViewModel = TestViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
        
        Button(action: {
            $testModel.test = "test2"
        }) {
            Text("[ Set value ]")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var test = "test"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need the `Binding` to set the value, you don't need `$testModel`, just `testModel`.

Change code to this:

```
Button(action: {
    testModel.test = "test2"
}) {
    Text("[ Set value ]")
}
```

It's also worth noting that you should use `@StateObject` rather than `@ObservedObject` here to prevent `TestViewModel` potentially being initialized multiple times.